# How I can embed pygal charts in django templates

Tags: django, django-templates, pygal

I use pyGal for making charts, but I can't insert them in django templates. 
It works great, if I try like this in views.py

```
 return HttpResponse(chart.render())
```

But when I make something like this in my template in doesn't work at all

```
 {{chart.render}}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The tutorial on pygal is accurate, however the issue you are probably seeing is from flask escaping html by default. In your template add:

```
{{ graph|safe  }}
```

or

```
{{ graph.render()|safe  }}
```

Depending what you pass to the template.

This solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 4):

This is what I do (and it works swimmingly!):

**views.py**:

```
def myview(request):
    # do whatever you have to do with your view
    # customize and prepare your chart
    # save SVG chart to server
    mychart.render_to_file('/path/to/graph.svg') 
    # end your view. For instance:
    context = {'message': 'Hello Pygal!'}
    return render(request, 'path/to/mytemplate.html', context)
```

**mytemplate.html**:

```
<embed type="image/svg+xml" src="/path/to/graph.svg" width="90"/>
```

That is all!

Answer (score 2):

I could write you the answer, but I believe that [this](http://pygal.org/en/stable/documentation/web.html) tutorial will provide a more detailed explanation.

Comment: I've already read this tutorial several times, but it didn't help. Maybe me is the problem ))

Answer (score 1):

multiple ways to do it

one way is

in temlate:

```
<div id="chart">
   <embed type="image/svg+xml" src= {{ chart|safe }} />
</div>
```

In django view :

```
return render(request, "temlate.html" , { 
    "chart": date_chart.render_data_uri()
})
```